# refresh page in JS setimeout function but keep form data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
setTimeout(function(){
      location.reload();
     },3000);
```

...*is* there any way; with similar format as the about `setTimeout` function to simply have the page refresh but to keep inputed form data there? so a refresh but keeping the form data that user has inserted. *(form data is just checkboxes btw)*

Comment: Yes, but... you would have to somehow send the form data from the current page to the new one, for example, through localstorage.

Comment: local storage, cookies, something to keep state, http is a stateless protocol

Comment: idd you can check javascript cookies if you want to keep it simple http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. before calling `refresh()` fetch values of inputs into collection.
2. store that collection in [sessionStorage/localStoarge](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
3. call `refresh();`
4. after loading check for that persisted data and if it is there populate inputs by those values.

Comment: Thanks, with this statement -- 'localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');' what is myCat?